# In Bash, is it possible to write an 'identity' function (relative to arguments passing/returning)

Tags: bash, variables, arguments, quotes, expansion

Such 'identity' function should satisfy the following 2 properties :

```sh
identity $(identity a\ b c\ d)
# (Expected output:)
# a b
# c d
```

And, given the following 'argv_count' function:

```sh
argv_count () { echo "argv_count('$@'):$#"; }
argv_count $(identity a\ b c\ d)
# (Expected output:)
# argv_count('a b c d'):2
```

Additional quotes could be introduced in the tests if need.

A simple candidate such as the following fail to pass the second test:

```sh
identity () { for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; done; }
```

**cat** is not a correct solution, as it is an identity function relative to stdin|stdout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The reason is that when the shell parses the output of a command substitution (that is, `$(somecommand)`), it performs word splitting and wildcard expansion *but no quote or escape evaluation*. This means that if `identity`'s output includes a space, the shell **will** treat that as a separator between "words" (i.e. arguments to the other program) no matter what quotes/escapes/whatever you add to try to avoid this. Worse, any wildcard-containing words in the output **will** be expanded into lists of matching files (if there are any). This means that `$(identity 'foo * bar')` is doubly doomed to failure.

With that said, there are ways to sort of fake it by changing the shell settings. For example, `set -f` will turn off wildcard expansion, solving that problem -- except that you have to set it in the parent shell before running `identity`, and then set it back to normal afterwards or lots of other things will break. Similarly, you could change IFS to prevent word splitting from treating spaces as separators -- but again you'd have to change it in the parent shell and set it back afterward, *and* it'd then cause trouble for whatever replacement separator character you chose. So you can fake it, but it's pretty bad fakery.

EDIT: As Michael Kropat pointed out, using `eval` is another way to "fake" it, and is more flexible if done carefully.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for those explanations ! To replace this in some practical context : does it means that no function can safely return a list of filenames (potentially containing spaces) as output ? Because unless using `eval` in the caller, you would lose the distinction between space & separator and hence could not loop through this list of files later on.

Comment: @LucasCimon: a function could return a list delimited by null characters (as `find -print0` does), but this cannot be used with the `$( )` construct -- you have to pipe it to something like `xargs -0` or a `while IFS= read -rd '' argument` loop. The reason this is "safe" is the same reason you can't use it with `$( )`: C strings cannot contain nulls, so neither arguments nor `$( )` can handle them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use `eval` you can work around the word-splitting on returned values:

```
$ argv_count a\ b c\ d
argv_count('a b c d'):2
$ identity() { printf ' %q' "$@"; }
$ eval argv_count "$(identity a\ b c\ d)"
argv_count('a b c d'):2
$ eval argv_count "$(eval identity "$(identity a\ b c\ d)")"
argv_count('a b c d'):2
```

Or with Gordon Davisson's trickier case:

```
$ argv_count $'foo\t * bar'
argv_count('foo  * bar'):1
$ eval argv_count "$(eval identity "$(identity $'foo\t * bar')")"
argv_count('foo  * bar'):1
```

Comment: There are a few weird cases where this doesn't work -- try `eval argv_count $(identity $'foo\t *  bar')` for example. I think if you add double-quotes around it like `"$(identity ....)"` it'll fix these cases.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Fascinating example! I have no clue why `eval argv_count $(eval identity $(identity $'foo\t * bar'))` works fine, but adding the `\t` breaks the simpler: `eval argv_count $(identity $'foo\t * bar')`. As for double-quotes as a fix, it breaks nestability I believe.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I up-voted yours as the correct answer btw. I only added my answer as an intellectual curiosity.

Comment: Actually, I think yours is a better kluge than the ones I suggested. The more complex version fails for me just like the simpler version; not sure why it'd work for you, but double-quoting does seem to nest fine, you just have to quote at each level: `eval argv_count "$(eval identity "$(identity $'foo\t * bar')")"` works as expected.

Comment: @GordonDavisson holy smokes it does work! I don't know what I was typing in wrong yesterday to get different results.